# How do capacity meters on USB drives if there is no battery or power source in the drive itself?

Tags: usb, battery

Some USB flash drives, such as the Lexar JumpDrive M10, have some sort of capacity meter on them, indicating the space left on the USB flash drive even when it is unplugged.

How does that work exactly? Is there a battery or something hidden in there that powers the display?

If there is no battery or such, could this used to make photo displays? Like the digital ones, but doesn't require recharging?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper

Comment: Seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you post as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the wiki entry for "electronic paper" posted by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  in your question, there are displays that don't need power to continue displaying an image, and the drive you mentioned likely relies on this tech.  This display could be updated while the drive is plugged into a computer, and the displayed result would stay accurate as nothing would be functionally added or removed from the drive while it's unpowered.